# ANTLR doesnt complain about unclosed comment

Tags: antlr, antlrworks

I'm trying to define a comment rule that allows `== bla bla bla ==` but not `==` on its own.

FYI, originally, I had added `F_COMMENT!?` between everything and still was getting the same problem. I've left one `F_COMMENT!?` in the `expression` rule in some vain attempt at getting it working.

When I debug `==` in ANTLRworks (1.5.2) it just ignores the `==` and returns the EOF token.

Heres some of the grammar...

```
expression
    :    F_COMMENT!? condition? EOF;

WS  
    :   ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' | F_COMMENT)+   { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;

F_COMMENT
    :    '==' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '==';
```

**UPDATE:**

I've created a concise grammar for this problem which seems to be working, for the `==` case at least...

```
@members {

    @Override    
    public void displayRecognitionError(String[] tokenNames,     RecognitionException e) {
    String hdr = getErrorHeader(e);
    String msg = getErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
    throw new RuntimeException(hdr + ":" + msg);
    }
}

expression
    :    condition? EOF;

condition
    :    (F_COMMENT!)* cnd_word;


cnd_word
    :    ( CND_WORD );

WS  
    :    ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' )+   { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;

CND_WORD
    :    ('=' | '*'? (F_QUOTEDWORD+ | F_WORDCHARS+) '*'?) | '*'; 

fragment
F_COMMENT
    :    '==' ~('=')* '==';

fragment
F_QUOTEDWORD
    : '"' (   ~('\\'|'"') | ('\\' '"') )* '"';     

fragment
F_WORDCHARS
    : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+;
```

Comment: But being on the `HIDDEN` channel should be fine shouldn't it? `F_COMMENT` shouldn't match `==` and hence it won't end up hidden. And thanks for pointing out the triviality of `greedy=false` :)

Comment: I've updated with a concise grammar. In the debugger I can see a UnwantedTokenException but this never gets thrown when I write a java unit test.

Comment: I dont know whats not clear for you, I want antlr to complain about unclosed comments. My update contains the entire grammar I was just testing with (minus the first line). Anyway, the revised grammar catches the unclosed comment and the overriden `displayRecognitionError()` causes an exception to be thrown which I am enable to handle in my code.

Comment: Never mind, I thought that I was again looking at a trimmed down version of your original grammar. Good to hear you found the issue.